# Faulty parallelism?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, parallelism

*It was more an inventive construction than based on serious historical research.*

Is it an example of faulty parallelism "construction/based", or is it acceptable if spoken with emphasis on "inventive"?

Comment: I think you need to give us more context in order to deal properly with this.

Comment: It was more an inventive construction than **one** based on serious historical research. ( *one* ='construction')

Comment: Context: Spengler's theory was highly speculative. It was more an inventive construction than based on serious historical research. Walter Laqueur called it "a guide for confused people".

Comment: @Kris That would be a good answer (with some explanation).

Answer (score 2):

> It was more an inventive construction than **one** based on serious historical research.
>  (*one* ='construction')

I thought that was rather obvious.

The author has either inadvertently omitted the parallel element, or has let it elide.